# how to package or bundle artifacts with JFrog Artifactory for configuration management purposes?

Tags: artifactory, packaging

We would like to *package* or *bundle* artifacts in JFrog Artifactory for configuration management purposes – how to achieve that?

We are able to deploy artifacts (RPMs in our case) to our JFrog Artifactory. But we need some packaging our bundling feature, that allows us to name the package resp. bundle, historize it, purge individual historical versions and of course let us look at the contents. I came across that feature "Release Bundles", but I am not sure it is what we want.

Our corporate configuration management calls that "baselining".

Answer (score 0):

What you describe are indeed the "release bundles" and support for those bundles (immutability, distribution, etc) is a part of [JFrog Enterprise+](https://jfrog.com/enterprise-plus-platform/).

Another view on a bundle (less coherent, but also valid) is considering a build as a bundle. Although artifacts aren't archived together, Artifactory has [metadata, which describes which artifacts are a part of the build](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration), and allows you [manipulating those artifacts together](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-BUILDS) (e.g. promote, download a zip, etc.).